# Using List<T> in C# (Generics)

Tags: c#, generics

That's a pretty elementary question, but I have never delved into generics before and I found myself in the need to use it. Unfortunately I don't have the time right now to go through any tutorials and the answers I found to related questions so far aren't what one could call basic, so there we go:

Let's say I have the following:

```
List<MyClass1> list1 = getListType1();
List<MyClass2> list2 = getListType2();

if (someCondition)
    MyMethod(list1);
else
    MyMethod(list2);
```

And of course

```
void MyMethod(List<T> list){
    //Do stuff
}
```

Well, I thought it would be this simple, but apparently it is not. VS warns me that

> The type arguments for method MyMethod(System.Collections.Generic.List) cannot be inferred from the usage

and if I compile it anyway, I get a

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found

error.

In the many answers I found, I read that I have to declare what `T` is, which makes sense, but I couldn't quite grasp how to do so in such a simplistic scenario. Of course, those answers created even more questions in my mind, but right now I just want an explanation of what I'm doing wrong (besides not studying generics) and how to make it right.

Comment: For one, make sure you have 
    using System.Collections.Generic; included.

Comment: That's not how generics work. `MyMethod(List<T> list)` is an invalid method signature (unless your class is a generic class with a Type Parameter `T`)

Comment: Do `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` have some common base type or interface? Do they share a lot of common properties or methods?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to declare `T` against the method, then C# can identify the type the method is receiving. Try this:

```
void MyMethod<T>(List<T> list){
    //Do stuff
}
```

Then call it by doing:

```
if (someCondition)
    MyMethod(list1);
else
    MyMethod(list2);
```

You can make it even stricter, if all classes you are going to pass to the method share a common base class:

```
void MyMethod<T>(List<T> list) where T : MyClassBase
```

Comment: C# will infer the type based on arguments, so explicitly specifying <MyClass1> isn't needed in this case - obviously if there are no parameters on the method, you will need to specify the generic arguments - but it's nice when they are inferred!

Comment: All answers work, I chose this one as the accepted for being the most complete (including @Charleh comment and the subsequent update). Thank you all.

Answer (score 18):

You need to add the generic type parameter for `T` to your method:

```
void MyMethod<T>(List<T> list) {
```

The compiler doesn't know what `T` represents, otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

You need to let c# know what type is sent:

```
List<MyClass1> list1 = getListType1();
List<MyClass2> list2 = getListType2();

if (someCondition)
    MyMethod<MyClass1>(list1);
else
    MyMethod<MyClass2>(list2);

void MyMethod<T>(List<T> list){
    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, In C#, `List < T >` class represents a strongly typed list of objects that can be accessed by index.

And it also supports storing values of a specific type without casting to or from object.

we can use in Interger value & String Value in the List.